# Books and resources for an entrepreneur inventor?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design

What books would you recommend for an inventor entrepreneur?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site. This question is also [primarily opinion-based](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), which makes it a bad fit for the StackExchange format, which is best for objective questions with one "right" answer.